# How to overlay a directional mean to hexbin plot in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

For Data Analysis purposes, I was trying to overlay information (like mean or median) over hexbin plots in Matplotlib.

As I did not encounter a solution on the web allowing to do so, I would like to share the solution that I'm using so far.

Any suggestions or comments welcome. Same goes for a prettier or more pythonic solution :)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def hexbin_red(mp_hex, ax="x", red_func=np.mean, mincnt=15):
    # Get x,y centers
    verts = mp_hex.get_offsets()
    cnts = mp_hex.get_array()
    
    # Prepare output arrays
    xx = []
    yy = []
    
    # Group by x or y value
    xvals = verts[:,int(0)]
    yvals = verts[:,int(1)]
    
    if ax=="x":
        aa = xvals
        bb = yvals
    elif ax=="y":
        aa = yvals
        bb = xvals
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"`ax` must be x or y not {ax}")
        
    a_unique = np.unique(aa)
    
    for k,val in enumerate(a_unique):
        xx.append(val)
        tmp_cnt = cnts[aa == val].astype(int)
        tmp_val = bb[aa == val]
        tmp = np.repeat(tmp_val, tmp_cnt)
        
        if len(tmp) > mincnt:
            yy.append(red_func(tmp))
        else:
            yy.append(np.nan)
    
    return np.array(a_unique), np.array(yy)
    

nx = 3000    
x = np.linspace(0,6.28,nx)
y = np.sin(x)
yn = y + np.random.rand(nx) * 0.5 - 0.25
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,2))
im = ax.hexbin(x,yn, mincnt=1,gridsize=40, cmap="terrain")

# Horizontal avg
x,y = hexbin_red(im,mincnt=3)
ax.plot(x,y,color="darkred",alpha=1,label="horzon. average",zorder=5)

# Vertical avg
x,y = hexbin_red(im,ax="y", mincnt=3)
ax.plot(y,x,color="blue",alpha=1,label="vertical average",zorder=5)

ax.legend()
fig.savefig("hexbin_example.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting image]

Comment: Could you detail your exact question? What is it you don't like about your current solution? How do you want it different?  Would seaborn's [`jointplot(kind='hex', ...)`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) be of interest?

Comment: Probably the form is misleading ! I don't specially have problems with my solution. It is just a question that I asked to myself I and did not find a corresponding question on this forum so I wanted to share both my objective and one way to deal with it.